# Javascript Jquery - Change Label Color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have this code:

```
 jQuery('#novaPasse').on('keyup',function(){
            var pass = $(this).val();

            if (IsEnoughLength(pass) && HasMixedCase(pass) && HasNumeral(pass)){
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Muito Forte!');
                $('#forcaPasse').prev('label').css('color','#8EFA00');
            }else if (IsEnoughLength(pass) && HasMixedCase(pass)){
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Forte!');
                $('#forcaPasse').prev('label').css('color','#7CDB00');
            }else if (IsEnoughLength(pass) && HasNumeral(pass)){
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Moderada!');
                $('#forcaPasse').prev('label').css('color','#FC9C35');
            }else{
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Fraca!');
                $('#forcaPasse').prev('label').css('color','#FF0000');
            }
            });
```

The goal is to change the color along with the text. Without the color code it works and it changes the text. But I want the text differently colored.The text appears but the color doesn't change. This is my Label

```
<label id="forcaPasse"></label>
```

Does anyone know how to change the color of the font of the label?

Comment: What you have should work. Can you also post your HTML so we can see how it's structured.

Comment: You are missing the `{}` arround your blocks. `if () { ... } else if () { ... } ...`

Comment: You were correct. I'll Edit. The color doesn't appear still

Comment: are you using LaraLevel?

Comment: Laravel. yes i'm using Laravel framework

Comment: Put alert box in each  If else and tell which Condition is executed Quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: I removed prev('label')

```
jQuery('#novaPasse').on('keyup',function(){
            var pass = $(this).val();

            if (IsEnoughLength(pass) && HasMixedCase(pass) && HasNumeral(pass)){
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Muito Forte!');
                $('#forcaPasse').css('color','#8EFA00');
            }else if (IsEnoughLength(pass) && HasMixedCase(pass)){
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Forte!');
                $('#forcaPasse').css('color','#7CDB00');
            }else if (IsEnoughLength(pass) && HasNumeral(pass)){
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Moderada!');
                $('#forcaPasse').css('color','#FC9C35');
            }else{
                $('#forcaPasse').text('Palavra-Passe Fraca!');
                $('#forcaPasse').css('color','#FF0000');
            }
            });
```

Now it works correctly!

Comment: what did you change here . LET US ALSO KNOW.

Comment: he removed `.prev('label')`